# Two networks without VLAN. Is is possible?

Tags: vlan

I wonder if there is necessary to create two VLANS to have two separate networks in a single switch. 
i.e. Having:

- Host A: 192.168.1.20 connected on port 1
- Host B: 192.168.1.21 connected on port 2
- Host C: 172.100.1.40 connected on port 3
- Host D: 172.100.1.41 connected on port 4

WITHOUT VLAN, isn't there any problems between network A-B and network C-D?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that.. but it is a realy realy bad set up.. and u should never ever ever do something like that.. it is a waste of router interfaces if you do that.

Comment: Overlay networks have been done for *decades*. There is nothing inherently wrong with the practice. If you use a cable modem, you live in a massive overlay network. (run tcpdump and watch all the arp's from subnets you aren't part of.)

Answer (score 0):

This will work without any problems, but of course A and C cannot reach eachother as well as B and D, unless there's a router connected to both IP networks.

Comment: ... or you tell the hosts about the other subnet(s) on the wire with them.